# Replace strings in a column in sas

Tags: arrays, sas, datastep

I want to replace all strings in a column with following:

```
strings  new_strings
ABC_MNO_S3  S1
ABC_S1      S2
ABC_S2      S3
ABC_PQR_S3  S4
XYZ_MNO_S3  S5
XYZ_S1      S6
XYZ_S2      S7
XYZ_PQR_S3  S8
```

So whenever any of the above *'string'* appear in my column **'states**' I want to replace it with *'new_string'* dynamically. I tried to put these list in an array and use `TRANWRD` to search through the column and replace, but not working.

My column states and the desired output looks like following:

```
states                 states_result
TR_ABC_MNO_S3_ABC_S2    TR_S1_S3
TR_ABC_S1_ABC_S2        TR_S2_S3
Segment                 Segment
ABC_PQR_S3              S4
TR_XYZ_MNO_S3_XYZ_S2    TR_S5_S7
Year                    Year
St_XYZ_S2               St_S7
```

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is answerable given how basic it is, but it would be better if you had included an example of the code you specifically tried here.

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourav:

Because you mentioned `TRANWRD` I will presume the `strings` values can be found embedded within a `states` value.  The key to effective use of `TRANWRD` is to `TRIM` the values when variables are used for the *target* and *replacement* arguments.

Replacement concerns:

- A single use of `TRANWRD` will work if there is only one target value 
  embedded.
- A loop over all targets would be needed if there can be more than one target value embedded.

There is a possibility that an earlier replacement could make rise a valid replacement that was not previously obvious. Consider the following `state` value:

```
ABC_ABC_MNO_S3
```

A first loop over all targets would replace `ABC_MNO_S3` with `S1` and yield

```
ABC_S1
```

A second loop over all targets would replace `ABC_S1` with `S2` and yield

```
S2
```

Tested sample:

```
data have;
infile cards dlm="," dsd;
length states segment year $100;
input states segment year;
datalines;
"TR_ABC_MNO_S3_ABC_S2 TR_ABC_S1_ABC_S2", "ABC_PQR_S3 TR_XYZ_MNO_S3_XYZ_S2", "St_XYZ_S2"
run;

data mappings;
length string $30 new_string $2;
input string new_string;
datalines;
ABC_MNO_S3  S1
ABC_S1      S2
ABC_S2      S3
ABC_PQR_S3  S4
XYZ_MNO_S3  S5
XYZ_S1      S6
XYZ_S2      S7
XYZ_PQR_S3  S8
run;

data want;
  array maps(100,2) $50 _temporary_; * first dimension must be larger than number of mappings;
  do _i_ = 1 by 1 until (lastmap);
    set mappings(rename=(string=_map_from new_string=_map_to)) end=lastmap;
    maps(_i_,1) = _map_from;
    maps(_i_,2) = _map_to;
  end;

  length status $12 _result $200;

  do until (lastdata);

    set have end=lastdata;
    array targets states segment year;

status = 'ORIGINAL'; 
output;

    do _i_ = 1  to dim(targets);

      _result = targets[_i_];
      _guard = 1;
      do until (_noreplacement or _guard >= 10);
        _noreplacement = 1;
        do _j_ = 1 to dim(maps,1) while(maps(_j_,1) ne '');
          if index(_result,trim(maps(_j_,1))) then do;

* put _result ': ' maps(_j_,1) '-> ' maps(_j_,2);

            _result = tranwrd(_result, trim(maps(_j_,1)), trim(maps(_j_,2)));
            _noreplacement = 0;
          end;
        end;
      end;

      if (_guard > 10) then do;
        put 'WARNING: Guard limit 10 reached, mappings may be cycling.' _result;
      end;

      targets[_i_] = _result;
    end;

    status = 'MAPS APPLIED';
    output;
  end;

  stop;
  drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: your code is giving me blank results. My data is following:  
  
  

`states`    
`TR_ABC_MNO_S3_ABC_S2`      
`TR_ABC_S1_ABC_S2`   
`Segment`    
`ABC_PQR_S3`    
`TR_XYZ_MNO_S3_XYZ_S2`    
`Year`    
`St_XYZ_S2`

Comment: Can you edit the original question and add the data information in a code block ?  The comment makes it look like you have three columns.

Comment: there's just one column. Edited the question to add the sample column and the desired output

Comment: The answer has been updated with tested code to handle an array of columns, so just change the variables listed for targets to just `state`.  The above code has two outputs for each input row, one for original and one for transformed.  You should be able to go forward on your own making a new column from _result instead of a new row.